# Push notifications from linux for iOS apps via SSL with PHP

Tags: php, ios, linux, ssl, apn

Do you know how to sent push notifications to IOS app from php? 
It's best answer for somebody http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
But it doesn't work:

```
        $production = 0;
        $passphrase = "kaka";
        $deviceToken = "bf38e156 29adac02 6b9b2ec6 35aa4381 df90df65 8238a13c d7f55261 798c3923";
        $message = "Hello people! What are you doing?";
        $deviceToken = str_replace(" ", "", $deviceToken);

        // Create a Stream
        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        // Define the certificate to use
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "local_cert", "CerAndKey.pem");
        // Passphrase to the certificate
        //stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "passphrase", $passphrase);
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "verify_peer", true);
        // load certificate
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "cafile", "CerAndKey.pem");

        if ($production) {
            $gateway = "gateway.push.apple.com:2195";
         } else {
            $gateway = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195";
         }

        $fp = stream_socket_client($gateway,
            $err,
            $errstr,
            60,
            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,
            $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect amarnew: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

        echo "Connected to APNS" . PHP_EOL;

        // Create the payload body
        $body["aps"] = array(
            "badge" => +1,
            "alert" => $message,
            "sound" => "default"
        );

        $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Ensure that blocking is disabled
        //stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        print_r($result);
        if (!$result)
            echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
            echo 'Message successfully delivered amar '.$message. PHP_EOL;

        // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: $deviceToken right and CerAndKey.pem is OK, but push notification can't come to iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Many people don't know how is right. PHP can diferent work in linux-systems. If you want I tell you howto easy use it.
Step by step:
1. Generate ssl keys:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## From
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344325/how-to-use-linux-openssl-to-generate-csr-for-ios

openssl genrsa -out ios-dev.key 2048
openssl req -new -key ios-dev.key -out ios-dev.csr

# You must upload to Apple -> Identifiers -> App IDs -> <project> -> edit -> Push Notifications -> Create Certificate ->
# then download -> aps_development.cer
# and put file here
```

2. Prepare key whith certificate for server script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
## from
# https://gist.github.com/stevenhaddox/1501893
# http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out CertAndKeyDevCert.pem
##cp CertAndKeyDevCert.pem /etc/ssl/certs/

openssl rsa -in ios-dev.key -out CertAndKeyDevKey.pem -outform PEM
cat CertAndKeyDevCert.pem CertAndKeyDevKey.pem > CertAndKey.pem
```

3.  Connect to Apple server for test

```sh
#!/bin/bash
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert CertAndKey.pem -key CertAndKey.pem -CAfile CertAndKey.pem
```

Result in console:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Root CA
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Application Integration Certification Authority
---
SSL handshake has read 3160 bytes and written 2176 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 5602BDD396ED4E8E9FE2BDFAD5A0226DEBB53C568EB34E57DE69E0024041F1F9F242A551E88758F5B0D4A2CDBEACBCB2
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1456218193
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Right responce:
1. verify return:1
2. Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Your certivicate and key are OK!
Next step is php-script:

```php
$production = 0;
        $keyFile = "CertAndKey.pem";
        $deviceToken = "bf38e156 29adac02 6b9b2ec6 35aa4381 df90df65 8238a13c d7f55261 798c3923";
        $message = "Ещё одно ...";

        $deviceToken = str_replace(" ", "", $deviceToken);

        if ($production) {
            $gateway = 'gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
         } else {
            $gateway = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
         }

        // Create the payload body
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'badge' => +1,
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
        );

        $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $filepath = "/tmp/sentPush.dat";
        file_put_contents($filepath,$msg);
        $command = "cat ".$filepath." | openssl s_client -connect ".$gateway." -cert ".$keyFile." -key ".$keyFile." -CAfile ".$keyFile." 2>&1";
        exec($command, $tmp);
        $last = end($tmp);
        unlink($filepath);
if ($last=="DONE"){
            $result = "Message successfully!";
         }else{
            $result = "ERROR:Message not send" . PHP_EOL;
         }
```

This solution will work somewhere, because I use only openssl.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

+1 is not allowed for badge

Store the badge number where you store the device tokens and update it with every push notification.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points that should be kept in mind:

- This problem might be occur due to `$production = 0;`. It should be `$production = true;`
- Try to use the full path for .pem file .=> `stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "local_cert", "CerAndKey.pem");` 
  use  `__FILE__` to get full path like: `stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "local_cert", "(full-path-to-file)/CerAndKey.pem");`
- Double check the device token used to send notifications.
- And in last try `chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $item[0])) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;`
  instead of

$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

May be it helps to you or someone else. Should try once.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips that should can help you figure out:

1. Go to [entrust.net/downloads/root_request.cfm](https://www.entrust.com/get-support/ssl-certificate-support/root-certificate-downloads/) and download entrust_2048_ca.cer
2. Add following code:
   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
3. Make sure if path is right: 'CerAndKey.pem'? not'../XXfolder/CerAndKey.pem' ?
4. Cancel the line of verify_peer setting;
   Instead, you should set passphrase - the password that you entered when exporting p12 from KeyChain.
5. Switch and try both the sandbox and live ssl links.
6. Switch dev and production pem and try both.