# how to create certificates, keys, .pem and .p12 file without using mac to create an ipa?

Tags: ios, certificate, ipa, pem, mobileprovision

I'm building a hybrid mobile application which is almost completed and working on testing phase.

My app is working fine on android devices but i need to test my app on IOS device. I have a Linux system on which i have done all the development. To create IPA i required x code but i don't have a Mac book.

I googled that how to create IPA online and i got the solution to create IPA and APK on [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com)  but it creates APK only. For IPA it required Some IPA key, certificates, .pem and .p12 file.

Can anybody suggest how to create all these certificates without x code?

Comment: Creating keys, and Provisioning Profiles for deployment - deveopment or otherwise, to iOS devices requires you have an Apple Developer account and these things are created on the http://developer.apple.com portal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This thing will work if you want to generate certificates for creating IPA.

Using a command line window:

1. cd C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin (or path to where you installed SSL)

if you are a linux user then open terminal with sudo su and start from step 2

2. openssl genrsa -out ios_distribution.key 2048
3. openssl req -new -key ios_distribution.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -subj /emailAddress=YOUEMAILADDRESS, CN=YOUR NAME, C=COUNTRYCODE
4. Go to https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/distribute.action218 and sign in. Go to “certificates” under iOS.
5. Under the Certificates menu on the left, click “All”, and then the “+” button aka: Add
6. Pick either a Development “iOS App Development” or a Production “App Store and Ad Hoc” certificate. Note: You will need to go through the process twice to have a development and a production version of the app.
7. Download the “Wordwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority” (AppleWWDRCA.cer) file from the same page
8. Click Continue until you get to the “Generate your certificate” screen. Upload the .certSigningRequest file you created earlier and click generate. Download the generated ios_development.cer file.
9. Create a Provisioning Profile by clicking on “All” under “Provisioning Profiles” on the left menu, and then clicking the “+” symbol, aka: add.
10. Again, you will need to create both Development and a Distribution (App Store) versions.
11. Create the Provisioning Profile for the App using the new .cer file (ios_development.cer)
12. Download the .mobileprovision file
13. In Command Prompt: openssl x509 -in ios_distribution.cer -inform DER -out ios_distribution.pem -outform PEM
14. openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios_distribution.key -in ios_distribution.pem -out ios_distribution.p12 -passout pass:PASSWORD
15. .key, .pem, and .p12 files will be generated

Answer (score 1):

For creating certificates you need an apple developer account. if you have one go to **Certificates & Identifiers** section from [developer account](http://developer.apple.com/). But you need a mac to create certificates as there is a **certificate request from certificate authority** to do using **keychain access** in mac. Unless you have a mac, i think its not possible to create `p12` certificates

Comment: I have developers account. but i dont have xcode or macbook to create certificates. i need to create .p12 certificate to create ipa

Comment: But you need a mac to create certificates as there is a **certificate request from certificate authority** to do using **keychain access** in mac. Unless you have a mac, i think its not possible to create certificates

Answer (score 0):

For Creating certificate, you need CSR file. For Creating CSR file from Linux, follow the link given below.

[How to use Linux openssl to generate CSR for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344325/how-to-use-linux-openssl-to-generate-csr-for-ios)

Then proceed with https://developer.apple.com/.

For creating p12 file from linux follow the instructions in the below links,

https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/288.html

[Creating a .p12 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141215/creating-a-p12-file)

Comment: i need tp create .p12 certificate but [How to use Linux openssl to generate CSR for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344325/how-to-use-linux-openssl-to-generate-csr-for-ios) not helping me to create .p12 file

Comment: i have added 2 links to my answer. Pls check

Answer (score 0):

Install VMWare/Parallels/Virtualbox (any virtual environment) on Windows machine and run MacOS.

Sample link: https://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox